# Dynamic variable into angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Into a first loop, which i recover an id, i try to define other loop like this :

```
    <ul ng-show="feed{{raterie.idFB}} === true" ng-init="var myFeed = myFeedFunction(raterie.idFB);">
        <li ng-repeat="feed in getFeeder(raterie.idFB) | limitTo:1">adoptions are : {{feed.title | cleanit}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="feed in feeder{{raterie.idFB}} | limitTo:1">adoptions are : {{feed.title | cleanit}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="feed in feeder{raterie.idFB} | limitTo:1">adoptions are : {{feed.title | cleanit}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="feed in feeder[raterie.idFB] | limitTo:1">adoptions are : {{feed.title | cleanit}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="feed in feeder['raterie.idFB'] | limitTo:1">adoptions are : {{feed.title | cleanit}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="feed in myFeed | limitTo:1">adoptions are : {{feed.title | cleanit}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="feed in feeder846097918756247 | limitTo:1">adoptions is : {{feed.title | cleanit}}</li>
    <ul>
```

I don't understand how to make 'feeder846097918756247' automatically constructed. The last li is what i want to get, i put it manually with only one example into first loop

I try two solutions into $scope :

```
    // define the value for ng-repeat (1st solution)
    $scope.getFeeder = function(id) {
        var idr = 'feeder' + id;
        return idr;
    }
    // define the value for ng-repeat (2nd solution)
    function myFeedFunction(pId) {
        return eval('feeder' + pId) ;
    }
```

It's doesn't work.

My online app is here : http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/pmr/

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you are asking. Instead of pointing to your live link. Prepare a plunkr and explain the problem statement.

Comment: I want to make 'feeder846097918756247' automatically constructed. The last li is what i want to get, i put it manually for show what i expected. '846097918756247' is in this case {{raterie.idFB}}

Comment: In the getFeeder if you do `return $scope[idr]` what happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inorder to get

```
<li ng-repeat="feed in getFeeder(raterie.idFB) | limitTo:1">adoptions are : {{feed.title | cleanit}</li>
```

to work, you need to return the array from the scope property in getFeeder function.

```
$scope.getFeeder = function(id) {
    return $scope['feeder' + id];
}
```

Or better, instead of putting `feeder846097918756247` directly on the scope as a property. Place the respective data in an object on scope.

i.e

```
 $scope.feeder = {};
 $scope.feeder['846097918756247'] = someArray;
//etc...
```

and just do:-

```
<li ng-repeat="feed in feeder[raterie.idFB] | limitTo:1">adoptions are : {{feed.title | cleanit}}</li>
```